# Ruby on Rails 4 Haml inline link_to interpolated external website url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, haml, link-to, string-interpolation

I have a Rails 4 project where I'm trying to display relevant information about the host of an event. I'm writing in Haml instead of ERB.

I want to render a string describing the type of information about the host, followed by the information. For example:

Email: abc@123.com

I was able to get the mail_to working properly with the following line, although I had to use .html_safe to achieve that. I've heard that is bad practice. Can anybody confirm that?

```
%p= "Email: #{mail_to @host.email}".html_safe
```

Now I'm trying to do something similar with a link_to for the host's facebook profile. The desired result is similar to the email. For example:

Facebook Profile: www.facebook.com/somebody

But I have been having trouble with this one, and after an hour of searching, I wasn't able to find a definitive solution.

I was able to get it working by splitting it into two lines.

```
%p Facebook Profile: 
  = link_to @host.facebook_profile, "http://#{@host.facebook_profile}"
```

But that displays the link on the following line. I tried to use the same format as the email example, but that didn't work.

```
%p= "Facebook Profile: #{link_to @host.facebook_profile, @host.facebook_profile}".html_safe
```

When I do that, it appends the facebook_profile url to the end of the current route.

```
http://localhost:3000/venues/facebook.com/somebody
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
%p= "Facebook Profile: #{link_to @host.facebook_profile, "http://" + @host.facebook_profile}".html_safe
```

Concatenate `@host.facebook_profile` with `http://` prefix so it becomes fully qualified url.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I know the + concatenation works in JavaScript, but I forgot that I can use it in Ruby as well.